# convex function bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

I'm trying to prove or disprove the next affirmation

Let $f:X\to [0,\infty)$ be a convex function such that $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is nonempty and bounded set, then the level sets of $f$ are bounded. ($(X,\| \ \|)$ is a reflexive space).

I could prove the affirmation when $X$ is a finite dimensional space (it's true), in the other case I haven't got any result, but I think that its false. I will be grateful if you can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$X=l_2$ and $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty {1 \over n} x_n^2$. Note that $f$ is convex, $f^{-1}(\{0\}) = \{0\}$.
However, $f^{-1}(\{1\})$ includes $\sqrt{n}e_n$ for all $n$.